# Android - SQLite query like MySQL

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, android-layout

I have the following to fetch data from android SQLite database

my function in android

```
public List<String> getMyDetails()
    {
            List<String> dataList = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM pic_details WHERE _id=1",null);

if (cursor .moveToFirst()) {

        do {
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
                dataList.add(name);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

return dataList;

}
```

In activity calling like this

```
List<String> piclist= dbHelper. getMyDetails();
```

Its returning the name of the candidate. But I want to return the entire column of the table something like this in PHP, MySQL

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pic_details WHERE _id=1");
$i=0;
$out=array();

while($t=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

$out[$i]['name']=$t['name'];
$out[$i]['file']=$t['file'];
$out[$i]['age']=$t['age'];
$out[$i]['date_time']=$t['date_time'];

$i++;
}

return $out;
```

So that I can fetch the $out according to my necessary.

Can any one please help me ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you provided in the `php code` in your question, it's not a single `column`. It's a `row data`. So, which you basically want is the entire row information. In order to get the entire row details, you have to do something like this.

```
 String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
 String address = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("address"));
```

So, the `generic` would be:

```
datatype fetchedData = cursor.getterofthatparticulardatatype(cursor.getColumnIndex(columnName));
```

**Edit:**

Either use `POJO class` as the other answerer said or this:

```
public List<HashMap<String, String>> getMyDetails()
    {

 List<HashMap<String, String>> datalist = new  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM pic_details WHERE _id=1",null);

if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

        do {
                HashMap<String, String> hashmap = new HashMap<String, String>();

                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
                String story = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("story"));

                hashmap.put("nameKey",name);
                hashmap.put("storyKey",story);

                dataList.add(hashmap);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

return dataList;

}
```

**The way you should retrieve:**

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> piclist= dbHelper. getMyDetails();

for(HashMap hashmap : piclist)
{
         String name = hashmap.get("nameKey");
         String story = hashmap.get("storyKey");
         Log.d("name,story",name+", "+story);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you create Java class.

```
public class Person {
    private String image;
    private String name;

    public Person(String image, String name) {
        super();
        this.image = image;
        this.name = name;

    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

Then create ArrayList of person class

Public List<Person> getMyDetails()
    {
            List<Person> dataList = new ArrayList<Person>();

    Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM pic_details WHERE _id=1",null);

if (cursor .moveToFirst()) {

        do {
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
              person = new Person(image, name)
                dataList.add(person);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

return dataList;

}

Then use this arraylist in you activity class.
```